# Find files in OneDrive shared with others

Tags: windows, file-permissions, onedrive

My company has OneDrive, and they are going through their internal auditing checks.  I need to check permissions on folders or files in my OneDrive account that I have shared, and review the permissions.  The company linked to a Microsoft help article that shows [how to view permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-sharing-onedrive-or-sharepoint-files-or-folders-or-change-permissions-0a36470f-d7fe-40a0-bd74-0ac6c1e13323#OS_Type=OneDrive,_SharePoint) for a specific file or folder.

Is there a command or way to show all folders/files in OneDrive that  I have shared?  I am a pack-rat and I have around 40,000 files, and 4,000 directories.  I have some high-level directories in  OneDrive I know I don't need to check, but there are several others that are suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I just needed to open my OneDrive tray icon, choose "View Online":

[image: Tray Icon]

Then in the web browser page displayed, choose "Shared" in the left-hand navigation pane.  Then on the right, click on the "Shared by you" tab!

[image: We Page menus]